# Query in pandas for closest object (in time) which meets a set of conditions

Tags: python, datetime, numpy, pandas

I am using Pandas to manage a set of files which have several properties:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Objtype'   : ['bias', 'bias', 'flat', 'flat', 'StdStar', 'flat', 'Arc', 'Target1', 'Arc', 'Flat', 'Flat', 'Flat', 'bias', 'bias'], 
        'UT'        :  pd.date_range("11:00", "12:05", freq="5min").values,
        'Position'  : ['P0', 'P0', 'P0', 'P0', 'P1', 'P1','P1', 'P2','P2','P2', 'P0', 'P0', 'P0', 'P0']}

df   = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

Which gives me a dataframe like this one:

```
    Objtype Position                  UT
0      bias       P0 2016-07-15 11:00:00
1      bias       P0 2016-07-15 11:05:00
2      flat       P0 2016-07-15 11:10:00
3      flat       P0 2016-07-15 11:15:00
4   StdStar       P1 2016-07-15 11:20:00
5      flat       P1 2016-07-15 11:25:00
6       Arc       P1 2016-07-15 11:30:00
7   Target1       P2 2016-07-15 11:35:00
8       Arc       P2 2016-07-15 11:40:00
9      Flat       P2 2016-07-15 11:45:00
10     Flat       P0 2016-07-15 11:50:00
11     Flat       P0 2016-07-15 11:55:00
12     bias       P0 2016-07-15 12:00:00
13     bias       P0 2016-07-15 12:05:00
```

I would like to index objects which meet a temporal condition in addition to another one. For example:

I want the the closest object to `Target1` whose `Objtype` is 'Arc'. For this query I would get two candidates: 6 and 8.

If for example I were to query the closest object to `Target1` whose `Objtype` is 'Arc' and shares the same `Position` (P2). I would get 8.

I am trying to slice the data frame according to the initial conditions and then using numpy but I am making a non-pythonic mess.

Any advice?

Comment: What do you mean by 'closest'? In this case, the only instances of `Objtype == 'Arc'` are the values just before and after `Target1`. Is this always the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's build a function

```
def get_closest(df, idx, bool_cond, to_this):
    others = df.loc[bool_cond, to_this]
    target = df.loc[idx, to_this]
    return df.ix[(others - target).abs().idxmin()]
```

First, assume when you are looking for somethihg closest to something else that we have a unique index.  If you don't, get it.  In this case, the index is `7` as that is the corresponding value to `'Target1'`.  Next, build a boolean series representing the conditions you care about.

```
cond1 = df.Objtype == 'Arc'
cond2 = df.Position == df.loc[7, 'Position']
```

Then we can call our function like:

```
get_closest(df, 7, cond1, 'UT')

Objtype                     Arc
Position                     P1
UT          2016-07-15 11:30:00
Name: 6, dtype: object
```

Perfect!  You mentioned there were 2 items just as close, I didn't care to deliver both.  I'll leave that as an exercise for you.  This function did deliver the row that was closest and satisfied the conditions.

What about:

```
get_closest(df, 7, cond1 & cond2, 'UT')

Objtype                     Arc
Position                     P2
UT          2016-07-15 11:40:00
Name: 8, dtype: object
```

Great!  That's what we wanted.

---

#### Explanation of `get_closest`

- `df` is the dataframe we care about.
- `idx` is the index that represents our target.
- `bool_cond` is the `True`/`False` series to slice our `df`
- `to_this` is the column name that we use to measure distance from.

---

```
def get_closest(df, idx, bool_cond, to_this):
    # filter dataframe
    others = df.loc[bool_cond, to_this]
    # get to_this value for target row
    target = df.loc[idx, to_this]
    # get index value for smallest absolute difference
    # and use it to get the resulting row
    return df.ix[(others - target).abs().idxmin()]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the great answer  (and the great explanations!!)